# Access to Chat Code?

Tags: discussion, chat, api, source-code

Ok, I'm not saying... "Let me have you chat code." I'm asking if its an open source project. I love the design of chat and well the entire interface in general. I'd love to incorporate a like client into my own project, but I'd have to do some adapt work and add some features that this site really doesn't need. I read in your FAQ that it might be an IRC client, so I was wondering if its an open source piece and where one goes to branch from it?

Otherwise, I'll have to rethink a chat client, and I don't want to that... Especially when a great one already exists.

Comment: P.S. My project is an open site, like SE just not an open source one... So, if their is an API. I'd greatly appreciate it and so would all those future users... You (SE) create fantastic software/platforms! I just want to build in some of that fantastic-ness to my own project. :)

Comment: I suspect that like the source to stack exchange, they consider the chat code one of their advantages over competitors.  I'd be very surprised to see them release it.  Of course you can pick apart the interface and the JS, and all you need to do is build a server behind it...

Comment: ...which as we all know is trivial.

Comment: Yes, or I could rewrite it to look and work similar, which is my worry. Technically that's not a legitimate thing to do nor a legally correct thing to do. Which is why I ask, will you share... sometime, maybe, in the decent future...

Comment: @Justin I am not a lawyer, but copying the rough structure of an UI should be extremely unlikely to cause legal trouble whatsoever. As long as you don't copy every pixel 1:1, rebuilding chat on your own should be completely fine -  although  obviously a *hellish* lot of work

Comment: Na... I'll only add make the site realtime... or compose something. It shouldn't take me more than a day.

Answer (score 5):

Chat is one of the main three places on this site, and as such is not available as an open source project.

There are parts of this site that *are* open source, like the [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/) and there are some things like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) that are ways that the team have repaid the community in kind, but the main components of the sites are not open for download.

That IRC thing was something somebody not affiliated with SEI worked on.

Comment: So... no help. Drat, well than could at least know what I'm legally permitted to do clone wise? 'Cause I love the whole twitter to stackExcahnge approach... I really do. (That's a bad analogy, but you get what I'm saying right?)

Comment: So if you think it's illegal it probably is. If you're not sure, mail team@ and ask someone, or pop into chat where we can probably help you faster ;) http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general